# Dependency problems using ews-javascript-api

Tags: angular, exchangewebservices

I installed `ews-javascript-api` via `npm i --save ews-javascript-api` to my Angular 4 project but when I require it an error occurs:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/fetch/lib/fetch.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in         
'C:\development\microservices\drk.crm.app.crm\node_modules\fetch\lib'
resolve 'dns' in 
'C:\development\microservices\drk.crm.app.crm\node_modules\fetch\lib'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: 
C:\development\microservices\drk.crm.app.crm\node_modules\fetch\package.json 
  (relative path: ./lib)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
   after using description file: 
C:\development\microservices\drk.crm.app.crm\node_modules\fetch\package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    resolve as module
 ...
```

How do I solve the missing dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should use this lib instead: https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-js-api-browser

Comment: Thanks, I also tried this and got it halfway running but meanwhile we decided to go with a Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.NETStandard service integrated in our graphql api gateway.